# Trouble with input trap (Among other things)

Tags: python, while-loop

So here I am again, clueless as always. I'm somewhat of a novice, so this is probably biting off more than I can chew, but whatever. 
The point of this program is to provide an output based off of input values from the user. It's meant to implement an input trap should the user not enter the correct input.

I'm trying to make it so the input of a letter or a non-integer value causes the message "Please enter only whole numbers." It works for the float points, but not letters. I should note that the "Enter a number between 0 and 10" message is working fine.
Also, the loop is supposed to close when the user inputs 'done', but that only results in a **"ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'done'"**.

I haven't written this in While True format as it's more comfortable for me to stick away from that method of writing while loops.

```
setCount = 1
 allScore = 0
 done = False
 while not done:
   strScore = float (input ( "Enter Set#" + str(hwCount) + " score: "))
if (strScore == int (strScore) and strScore >=0 and strScore <=10):
    totalScore = totalScore + (strScore)
    setCount = setCount + 1
elif ( setScore == int (strScore) and( setScore < 0 or setScore > 10)):
    print ("Please enter a number between 0 and 10.")
elif setScore != "done":
    print ("Please enter only whole numbers.")
else:
    done = True
```

Comment: How do you expect `float(input(..))` to work when the user enters `done`? Don't convert to `float` immediately when you expect the input might not be a float! Check if it's `done` first.

Answer (score 0):

You immediately convert the input string to a float on the same line where you read it:

```
strScore = float (input ( "Enter HW#" + str(hwCount) + " score: "))
```

In order to accept "done" as an input, you need to keep it as a string, and convert it to float (or int) after you have done all input validation.

drop `float()` and strScore will be a string. Then check if it equals "done". Finally, convert it to an integer inside a try block

```
print ( "Enter the homework scores one at a time. Type \"done\" when finished." )
hwCount = 1
totalScore = 0
while True:
    strScore = input ( "Enter HW#" + str(hwCount) + " score: ")
    if strScore == "done":
        break
    try:
        intScore = int(strScore)
    except ValueError:
        print ("Please enter only whole numbers.")
        continue
    if (intScore >=0 and intScore <=10):
        totalScore += intScore
        hwCount += 1
    else:
        print ("Please enter a number between 0 and 10.")
```

Comment: Alrighty, awesome. In that case, how would I write it?

Comment: @Liam i added a suggestion based on your example

Answer (score 0):

You should really clean your code up, all those extra spaces hurts readability. I'd suggest using PyLint (`pip install pylint`, `pylint file.py`).

I'm not going to refactor your code too much, but you need to check for 'done' before converting to a float. And you'll want to catch ValueErrors incase somebody enters an invalid answer and handle it gracefully.

```
print("Enter the homework scores one at a time. Type \"done\" when finished. Ctrl+c to quit at any time.")
hwCount = 1
totalScore = 0
try:
    while True:
        strScore = input("Enter HW#" + str(hwCount) + " score: ")
        if strScore == 'done':
            break #done
        else:
            try:
                strScore = float(strScore)
            except ValueError:
                print('Invalid input: must be a numerical score or "done"')
                continue
        if (strScore == int (strScore) and strScore >=0 and strScore <=10):
            totalScore = totalScore + (strScore)
            hwCount = hwCount + 1
        elif ( strScore == int (strScore) and( strScore < 0 or strScore > 10)):
            print ("Please enter a number between 0 and 10.")
        elif strScore != "done":
            print ("Please enter only whole numbers.")
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass #done
```

Heres a more complete version of your program, for reference. It's how I would have refactored it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def findmode(lst):
    bucket = dict.fromkeys(lst, 0)
    for item in lst:
        bucket[item] += 1
    return max((k for k in bucket), key=lambda x: bucket[x])

print("Enter the homework scores one at a time.")
print("Type 'done' when finished or ctrl+c to quit.")
scores = []
try:
    while True:
        strScore = input("Enter score: ")
        if strScore == 'done':
            break #done
        else:
            try:
                strScore = int(strScore)
            except ValueError:
                print('Invalid input: must be a score or "done"')
                continue
        if (0 <= strScore <= 10):
            scores.append(strScore)
        else:
            print("Please enter a valid score between 0 and 10.")
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass # user wants to quit, ctrl+c
finally:
    print("Total scores graded: {}".format(len(scores)))
    print("Highest score: {}".format(max(scores)))
    print("Lowest score: {}".format(min(scores)))
    print("Mean score: {}".format(sum(scores)/len(scores)))
    print("Mode score: {}".format(findmode(scores)))
```

Comment: Good to know. I'll work on my spacing with coding. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Liam I've refactored the code a little bit and posted how I would have likely structured the program. Figured it would be a good opportunity for you to learn.